# WHERE value is not equal some pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to filter out all values which have in a column something like '74xxxx/xxxx' and return only those which have a number in the format 123456/7890 or 123456/789.

```
    SELECT TOP(100)
     Pocet  = COUNT(CisloSmlouvy)
    ,Jmeno = KliRC
FROM dbo.Smlouvy
WHERE KliRC ....
GROUP BY KliRC
ORDER BY 
    Pocet DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my question, since I realised it's trivial :-)

```
SELECT TOP(1)
     Pocet  = COUNT(CisloSmlouvy)
    ,Jmeno = KliRC
FROM dbo.Smlouvy
WHERE KliRC NOT LIKE '%x'
GROUP BY KliRC
ORDER BY 
    Pocet DESC
```

Sorry for messing up.

Comment: Ah. For reference, your question could stand to be improved. When I read the spec, I assumed the `74` part was important and that the `x`s were being used as an "anything can go here" type of placeholder. More examples/explanation would probably make the question clearer. Rather than just stating "something like '74xxxx/xxxx'", better stated would be "containing any `x` characters, e.g. '74xxxx/xxxx'"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to find there are different possibilities:

- find numbers in the format 123456/7890 or 123456/789:

  ```
  (...)
  WHERE
      KliRC LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
      OR KliRC LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
  (...)
  ```
- find values that don't contain 'x' at any postion

  ```
  (...)
  WHERE
      KliRC NOT LIKE '%x%'
  (...)
  ```
- find values that don't end on 'x' (like you figured put already)

  ```
  (...)
  WHERE
      KliRC NOT LIKE '%x'
  (...)
  ```
- find values that only contain numbers or the character `/`

  ```
  (...)
  WHERE
      KliRC NOT LIKE '%[^0-9/]%'
  (...)
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You Might wanna visit,
[Regex in SQL query](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/using-regular-expressions-regex-in-sql-server-to-generate-randomized-test-data/)
This will help u in biggwe run.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP(100)
 Pocet  = COUNT(CisloSmlouvy)
,Jmeno = KliRC
FROM dbo.Smlouvy

WHERE ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(cislosmlouvy,1,6)) = 1
AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(cislosmlouvy,8,12)) = 1
AND cislosmlouvy NOT LIKE '74%'

GROUP BY KliRC
ORDER BY 
    Pocet DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer that @dd4711 posted is probably what you need. Here's a clean alternative for dealing with this kind of problem. Let's say you wanted to return all records with 6 numbers followed by a forward slash, then 2-4 numbers. You could do this:

```
DECLARE @sometable TABLE (id int identity, somestring varchar(100));
INSERT @sometable (somestring) 
VALUES ('ABC'),('123456/xxx'),('555555/22'),('555555/333'),('999999/4444'),('88888/55');


SELECT id, somestring 
FROM @sometable
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (2), (3), (4)) N(N)
WHERE somestring LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/'+REPLICATE('[0-9]', N);
```

Which returns:

```
id          somestring
----------- ------------
3           555555/22
4           555555/333
5           999999/4444
```

Taking this one step further, let's say you needed 5-6 numbers followed by a forward slash then 2-4 more numbers... You could do this:

```
DECLARE @sometable TABLE (id int identity, somestring varchar(100));
INSERT @sometable (somestring) 
VALUES ('ABC'),('123456/xxx'),('555555/22'),('555555/333'),('999999/4444'),('88888/55');

SELECT id, somestring 
FROM @sometable
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (5), (6)) N1(N)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (2), (3), (4)) N2(N)
WHERE somestring LIKE REPLICATE('[0-9]', N1.N)+'/'+REPLICATE('[0-9]', N2.N);
```